# Accessing Voice Mail Services in Windows Phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7

I am creating a module for my project which is location based profile change in Windows Phone 7.

I am giving an extra feature in my app. When a user recieves a call, when in a certain profile (i.e silent or driving), the incoming call will recieve a service like voice mail where he/she can record a message.

Which API can I use to achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

It's not entirely clear what you're after but I'm certain you can't do it:

There is no API for accessing profile information.

There is no API for accessgin call history details.

There is no way to determine if your application is being obscured for an incoming call or another reason.

Access to voicemail is operator dependent. There is no universal way to access this. Some oeprators provide their own APIs for accessing things like voicemail but these vary in implementation, availability and capabilites.